# How does the overlap area between two circles change as the two circles are moved apart?

Tags: geometry, circles

I am wondering how the overlap between two identical circles changes, from a situation where their centres overlap (and hence they 100% overlap) until the distance between the centres remains < radius.

Comment: If the area was proportional to $1/d^2$ then the area would never reach zero, but once $d$ is greater than the sum of the radii of the two circles, there is no overlap, so the area must be zero. It follows that the answer is no.

Comment: @DavidSheard proportional doesn't necessarily mean 1/d^2. But can I ask then how it relates to the distance?

Comment: This is a relatively simple case of area of [circular lunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(geometry)).  If you know the area of a lune, you can get the area of the overlap by subtracting (or by more direct computation, given the symmetry of the "two identical circles").  Can you articulate what motivates your Question, or in some other way provide *context* for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the distance between the centres be $d$ and let each circle have radius $r$. Let the centres of the circles be $O$ and $O'$ and let the circles intersect at $P$ and $Q$.

The angle $A$ between $OO'$ and $OQ$ is then given by $\cos A=\frac{d}{2r}$.

The area of sector $OPQ$ is then $ r^2 A$ whereas the area of triangle $OPQ$ is $\frac{1}{2} r^2 \sin 2A$.

The difference between the area of the sector and the area of the triangle is half the area of overlap so the formula you want is $$r^2(2A-\sin 2A).$$